# how to stop Foreground service notification 'noise' programmatically when invoking notification UI display

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, foreground-service

I don't know why, but for some reason, whenever I use the `startForeground(...)` or the `notificationManagar.notify(...)` command on android `oreo` and above there is a notification sound that lasts almost 1 second.

This wouldn't be a problem, if it only sounded the first time, but, it sounds everytime whenever I update the notification UI (which is again done by doing the `notificationManager.notify`.

Is there some way I can disable this sound while my app is active?(since, I don't know why the system would need it, but, there must be something the system has designed it for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As notification channels are a must for Oreo+ APIs, then this is most probably related to the channel.

I think you can stop this sound by using [`NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_LOW) while creating the Foreground service notification channel.

```
NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW // <<<<<
        );

NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
```